# Print every 10 characters in a record

Tags: linux, bash

This is my file

```
inavgmcn,inavg7ey    evl33001897,evl308971,evs3300142,evh8890123
inavgmcn,inavg7ey,pwdelf46,krpuram1,kundur12    evl3301897,evl3308971,evs3300142,evh8890123
pwdelf46,krpuram1,kundur12  evl3308971,evs3300142,evh8890123
```

I tried to separate the two fields in a every record and print to cut every 8 charters into new lines, with my command i getting half part only, could any one help on this as below out put.

**MY Command**

```
awk ' BEGIN {printf ("%-10s\t%-10s\n","USERS", "HOSTNAMES" )}; { printf ("%-.8s\t%-7s\n", $1,$2) }' filename

USERS           HOSTNAMES  
inavgmcn        evl33001897,evl3308971,evs3300142,evh8890123
```

**Expecting OUTPUT**

```
USERS                   HOSTNAMES  
inavgmcn                evl3301897
inavg7ey                evl3308971
                        evs3300142
                        evh8890123

inavgmcn                evl3301897
inavg7ey                evl3308971
pwdelf46                evs3300142
krpuram1                evh8890123
kundur12        

pwdelf46                evl3308971
krpuram1                evs3300142
kundur12                evh8890123
```

This is the output I'm trying to first field cut in a record every 8 characters and remain comes to next new line, as same 2nd field cut in a record 10 characters and remain  characters  comes to next new line.. Please let me know if my question not understandable...

Comment: Unclear how output will be achieved. Can you add more clarification?

Comment: It's not clear how your second line will be parsed.  First line looks comma separated, but not the second line.  For formatting columns side by side better look at `paste` command.  For example  `paste <(seq 1 2) <(seq 10 15)`  will print two columns, first one will list 1 and 2, whereas second one will have 10 to 15.

Comment: Edited my question and please answer me for the first record only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the output you shared. This is the best possible solution I can suggest.

```
(echo -e "\nUSERS\n";    awk '{printf $1",\n"}' filename | tr ',' '\n') > file1
(echo -e "\nHOSTNAMES\n";awk '{printf $2",\n"}' filename | tr ',' '\n') > file2
```

Temporary files file1 & file2 are created. file1 stores all the users and file2 stores all the hostnames.
Below command gives the format you wanted.

```
diff -y file1 file2|tr -d ["|><"]
```

Once the required data is captured, you can delete the unwanted files.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear but based on the sample output, below script may be helpful.

```
paste <(awk '{print $1}' filename|tr ',' '\n') <(awk '{print $2}' filename|tr ',' '\n')
```

Above script may not give you the text format you expected but I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: that command not showing any out put , could you please check again

Comment: @DasD : I worked on the same sample data you provided and I am getting the exact output you needed. check the file name and run the command again.

Comment: @"Venkat Madhav:. its working with the above command , you missed that one left Parentheses, after last end of the line '\n')

Comment: Could you please check with the same command for for two lines,for one record  that output  getting as expected , when i try for two lines  getting some changes for the output.. please try and help me ,

Comment: @DasD : If you can share  a sample input with more than 3 lines, then it may help fix the problem.

Comment: I've added three lines in my question for that can u pls pls try with your command and provide me as my expected output solution, thanks a ton for your  quick response...

Comment: Can you provide the expected output for the new input which you shared?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79497/discussion-between-das-d-and-venkat-madhav).